# Can I debug in gdb multiple processes and/or threads simultaneously, that is, halting all of them once one hits a breakpoint?

Tags: multithreading, gdb

As in the title.

Sometimes step-by-step debugging of a process or a thread becomes inconvenient if other threads/processes continue their execution at full speed.

Bonus if it was possible to debug this way two processes when they were both started independently from bash (and not one a child of the other).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/856488/72178 ?

Answer (score 1):

For threads, this should *already* be happening.

GDB by default executes inferior in *all-stop* mode. In that mode, GDB will stop all threads as soon as one thread stops (either because it received a signal, or because it encountered a breakpoint). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/858430/50617).

While GDB also supports multiple inferiors, I don't believe there are any mechanisms to perform a "stop all inferiors" equivalent to "stop all threads" built in to GDB.

However, you can trivially achieve that with a command attached to your breakpoint:

```
(gdb) break foo.c:1234
(gdb) commands 1
  shell kill -STOP 4321   # stop the other inferior
end
```

> Bonus if it was possible to debug this way two processes when they were both started independently from bash

Sure: you can attach both processes to the current GDB (`(gdb) help attach`) or to separate ones. It doesn't much matter where they were started from.